# Parsing chef environment attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

In a chef environment I have the following attributes:

```
"recipe": {
   "attribute1": {
       "name1": {
           "description": "some description",
           "permissions": "read"
        },
       "name2": {
           "description": "some description",
           "permissions": "write"
        },
   }
}
```

I need somehow to put in a variable x the value of 'permissions' for each element of the attribute.

Like in:

```
attribute1.each_with_index do |value, index|
  if value.permissions="read"
     #do something
  else
     #do something else
  end
end
```

What I need is to know how to store in a variable the value of 'permissions' in  attribute1.each loop.

```
x=value.permissions  ?!
```

Thank you.

Comment: don't get your point

Comment: with "in a variable", do you mean a _list_ or an _array_ so that you accumulate _all_ permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
node["recipe"]["attribute1"].map do |key, value|
  value["permissions"]
end
```

That will give you a list like `["read", "write"]`.

If you instead want a hash like `{"name1" => "read", "name2" => "write"}` you want:

```
node["recipe"]["attribute1"].inject({}) do |memo, (key, value)|
  memo[key] = value["permissions"]
  memo
end
```